# angular2 - cannot find browser,corejs

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am including ng2-bs3-modal for creating modals in angular2 , according to this [thread](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/761) . Since the ng2-bs3-modal and the js files that it loads (like modal.js, modal-header.js) does not take .js as their extension by default , i had to use deafultJsExtension: true to achieve that . To prevent angular errors according to that same thread(angular is loading its modules again in the browser), i included system.config directly after loading systemjs , instead of writing it after loading angularjs,

```
 <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js">
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js">
    </script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
          defaultJSExtensions: true,
          packages: {
            angular: { defaultExtension: false },
            app: {
              format: 'register',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
          },
          map: {
              'ng2-bs3-modal': 'node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal',
          }
        });
        System.import('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
        System.import('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        System.import('app/js/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js">
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js">
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js">
    </script>
```

Now, sometimes it works fine, sometimes it says that browser.js, core.js not found, also system.js error

(in console it says GET http://localhost:3000/angular2/core.js 404 (Not Found)  -- system.src.js:1068
Assertion failed: loading or loaded  -- system.src.js:291

can someone identify this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer was quite obvious from the error , i had to write a map for angular2 as well ::-

```
map: {
       'ng2-bs3-modal': 'node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal',
       'angular2': 'node_modules/angular2'
     }
```

Maybe this had to do with the sequence of files and polyfill scripts loading, but this sequence was taken from sources i read on the internet and nowhere it was written that we may encounter such error.

It is happening with everyone right ? Or is it just me